# Html Tags end up with my responsive design

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML/CSS code, and you can see it in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nojy1cdm/)

```
<div id="geral">

<div id="topo">

</div>

<div id="meioPage">

<div id="Menu_B">

</div>

<div id="Feed">

</div>

<div id="Menu_C">

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

The problem with this code is that it was made to take over the entire screen (responsive design) and its minimum size is 800x600 and its maximum size is 4k (more than that he did not make it a responsive design)

In a strange way the code works perfectly without the HTML tags, now I added these tags in my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

//Here I put the other code up

    </body>
</html>
```

And the responsive design stopped working, and it no longer occupies the entire screen.

An example is the page the link sent above, JSFddle site automatically adds the HTML tags, but if you test this code without tags will see the responsive design come back to work, how can I solve this problem? there is some code to be placed in the HTML tags?

Comment: only thing I can think of is that the body tags are overriding something

Comment: _"In a strange way the code works perfectly without the HTML tags, now I added these tags in my code and the responsive design stopped working, and it no longer occupies the entire screen."_ - Which tags did you add after the fact? On a different note, I checked your link above. What exactly is it doing that it's not supposed to or, contrarily, what's it not doing that it's supposed to? Your question is a little unclear...

Comment: @War10ck I create this code without the HTML tags, and when I finish my code I add the HTML tags, and for my surprise the responsive design not work anymore....

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a really good comparison. Your first markup is completely invalid. It would be anyone's guess as to how the browser decides to render that. Chrome for example will usually wrap the code with an HTML5 Doctype, `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. You should consider designing using the second snippet as it contains a fully valid page. To my second question above though, what's not happening that you want to happen?...

Comment: @LettersBa Is it the height that is getting messed up?

Comment: It probably 'worked' because you did not have a Doctype declared and it was not properly structured. Changing Doctype can easily change the way the site displays. Structure it correctly like the edit and edit the CSS would be my suggestion.

Comment: @LettersBa Since you are adding `html` and `body` tags you may need to specify a height for both of those tags for your percentage heights to work

Comment: Hey Guys! I find one Solution but is not the best! I put inside the tag #Geral this code "position:absolute;" and my responsive design come back to work 98%....

Comment: Well I believe I will leave my code this way (without the html tags), since when I run my code in the browser google chrome automatically inserts the tags (I saw it by clicking inspect element), so I believe that has not problems enter these tags in the code since the browser automatically adds ...

Answer (score 0):

add meta viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

when making responsive website you must put this in you head tags so the browser knows it is responsive, same for mobile devices.